# Get HTTP Status using swift

Tags: http, swift, httprequest

I am sorry, I haven't found an answer for my question(( Please, don't be very harsh, I am not a professional programmer, but I keep learning and hope once I will be able to answer someone's question))

I am trying to get HTTP Status of the link (I am sort of generating links depending on one database entries code, like ABCDEF, I keep them in an array and then generate a link to second database, like www.blablabla.ABCDEF.net), so I can see whether the page exists in database or not.

I have written this code, but something is wrong. So maybe it's a question like: "What's wrong with my code?" But on the stack they also say, you have to show your attempts of problem solving...

I wish I could keep it all swift, without any additional modules or something, I think `NSHTTPURLResponse` must be enough, but I am using it somehow wrong.

Looking forward to help and replies))

```
var err: NSError!

NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: queue, completionHandler:{ (response: NSURLResponse?, data: NSData!, error: err) -> Void in

    if (err != nil) {
        let httpStatus: NSHTTPURLResponse = response as NSHHTPURLResponse
        for myLink in allLinks {
            println("HERE IS THE CURRENT STATUS CODE" + httpStatus.statusCode + "OF A LINK:" + myLink)
            if httpStatus.statusCode == 200 {println("SUCCESS!!!!!")}
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The fundamental issue here is that you appear to be looking at the `statusCode` only if the `err` is not `nil`. But if you have error, you probably don't have status code. The error parameter to the closure indicates fundamental network issue that probably prevented you from getting to the page in question. The `statusCode` is generally only meaningful if the error *was* `nil` (i.e. you succeeded in connecting to the server), in which case the `statusCode` is how the server informs you of its ability to service the HTTP request.

A couple of minor things:

1. You don't need the `var err: NSError!` line (because the `error` object is passed as parameter to  the closure). This variable you've declared is not used here.
2. I don't see how `error: err` as the third parameter to the closure could have worked. The syntax is  "variableName: variableType", but there is no type of `err`.
3. Likewise, your code is referring to a non-existent class, `NSHHTPURLResponse`. In Swift 3 and later, it's `HTTPURLResponse`.
4. It's probably prudent to do `if let` for the retrieval of the `HTTPURLResponse` in order to get the `statusCode`.
5. I'm unclear as to your intent in iterating through `allLinks`, because this connection is just for a given `request`, not a bunch of links. Just look at the `statusCode` in light of the particular `request`. If you need to test multiple URLs, then you do a separate `request` for each.
6. We should consider any codes between 200 and 299 as success, not just 200. I'd suggest using the range `200 ..< 300`.

Thus:

```
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
    guard let data = data, let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse, error == nil else {
        print("No valid response")
        return
    }

    guard 200 ..< 300 ~= httpResponse.statusCode else {
        print("Status code was \(httpResponse.statusCode), but expected 2xx")
        return
    }

    // everything OK, process `data` here
}
task.resume()
```

I also made a few other changes (updated for Swift 3 and later; use `URLSession` rather than `URLConnection`; I think `error` is fine choice for the variable name; I prefer the trailing closure syntax; I tend to use inferred types for closure parameters to make the declaration a little more concise, etc.), but all of that is immaterial to the question at hand: Hopefully this illustrates how one checks the status code.

For Swift 2 rendition, see [previous revision of this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/26565883/1).

Comment: Thank you. I have also decided not to give up and when waiting for someone's help written another code (working!), but yours seems to be better and sort of tidier)
Here is what I've done to request (when trying to make something workable myself): 'let urlPath: String = allLinks[i]
            var url: NSURL = NSURL(string: urlPath)!
            var request: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: url)'
So it goes step by step through each link in array and requests for them, because this code itself if inside a for-loop.
And great thanks for explanations I wish I could vote up, but reputation(

Answer (score -1):

[Swift 5.2]
Hi there, you can try this one:

```
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: yourRequest) {
      (data, response, error) in
      guard let response = response else {
        print("Cannot found the response")
        return
      }
      let myResponse = response as! HTTPURLResponse
      print("Status Code:", myResponse.statusCode)
    }
    task.resume()
```

Here is the output

> Status Code: 200

(This is your StatusCode)